# XML Reading Issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following XML doc...  I have just left one "line" in for simplicity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
  <file type="INVOICES">
    <document>blah.pdf</document>
    <line>
        <field name="JobNo">321654</field>
        <field name="Issues">1</field>
        <field name="PageCount">200</field>
        <field name="PrintRun">250</field>
        <field name="Size">Small</field>
    </line>
  </file>
</files>
```

C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("input.xml");
    XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//files/file/line");
    foreach (XmlNode itemNode in itemNodes)
    {
         XmlNode jobNo = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("field");

         if (jobNo != null) 
              Console.WriteLine(jobNo.InnerText);
     }
     Console.ReadKey();   
}
```

This iterates through each line and displays the job number however I want to access the field by it's name `JobNo` i.e. 
`<field name="JobNo">321654</field>`  accessed with...

```
jobNo = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("JobNo");
```

I know I can change the xml but the XML is supplied by a customer so this is not really an option.

Comment: So, what you want basically? To read out all "JobNo" values (321654, ....) from the xml?

Comment: well yes and be able to access the other fields in the same way. i.e.   issues pagecount etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that specific field element by providing the attribute name and value such as

```
XmlNode jobNo = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("field[@name='JobNo']");
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i am looking for.